# Try/Catch fails to catch exception in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-server-2012, try-catch

I'm struggling to get my try/catch to work with my stored procedure, it seems to not catch the error.  I've been searching around, but no luck.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the error number if an invalid value, no value, or null is given when the stored procedure is called.  I've tried moving the try and catch it feels like everywhere, but it seems like the error may be on the "@SomeID as int" line.  I appreciate any help I can get.

```html
alter procedure DeleteAcct
@SomeID as int
as
begin try
declare @counter int
set @counter = (select count(SomeDate) from Table1 where SomeID = @SomeID group by SomeID)
begin
 if(@counter > 0)
 begin
 Print 'Testing'
 end
 else 
 begin 
 delete from Table2
 where SomeID = @SomeID
 Print 'Delete successful'
 end
end
end try
begin catch
 print error_number()
end catch

<!-- calling the stored procedure -->
exec DeleteAcct '1231231231221'

<!-- Error received -->
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure DeleteAcct, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to int.
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare param `@SomeID` as an `int` then try to pass a string!

Make call like so:

```
exec DeleteAcct 1231231231221
```

In fact I suspect `@SomeID` should be declared as a `varchar`

Comment: I tried that, but it still gives me an error. Error converting data type numeric to int.  It doesn't print off the error_number

Answer (score 1):

Well this answer is late, but we do this at work all the time.
You should try/catch the launcher and not the SP that is being executed.

I believe the explanation was quite obvious, but lets develop:

1. The called procedure does not need any try/catch:

```
    alter procedure DeleteAcct
    @SomeID as int
    as
    declare @counter int
    set @counter = (select count(SomeDate) from Table1 where SomeID = @SomeID group by SomeID)
    begin
        if(@counter > 0)
        begin
        Print 'Testing'
        end
        else 
        begin   
        delete from Table2
        where SomeID = @SomeID
        Print 'Delete successful'
        end
    end
```

2. The launcher or the calling procedure needs to be put into try/catch block so that the error from the executed procedure is displayed at the launcher level.

```
    begin try
        exec DeleteAcct '1231231231221'
    end try
    begin catch
        print error_number()
    end catch
```

Comment: Removed review queue commend and upvoted as the answer was edited since [it's first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41827026/1)